# how to resolve radio button problem when we changing the orientation?

Tags: android

hi all how to implement code for Radio button when i take the radio group i take only two radio buttons from that radio button when i select the second radio button after changing the orientation second radio button is disable (i mean when i select the second radio button in the portrait   mode if i change to  landscape mode radio button first one is enable and  second one disable but my intention is second have to be enable )how to solve this problem so plz help me over come from this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `android:configChanges="orientation"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` of that Activity.

Answer (score 0):

When changing orientation on Android, the activity is reinitiated, i.e. it is destroyed and then restarted. What you need to do is to save your current state in the OnDestroy method and read it in the OnCreate method.

Read more on the android development webpage on [activity lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)